# Serve main directory from subdomain URL without redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have a ***http.//domain.com*** served at **/var/www/domain**

I also a ***http.//subdomain.domain.com*** served at **/var/www/domain/subdomain**

When a user visits **http.//subdomain.domain.com** i want apache to serve **/var/www/domain**

I have been looking everywhere and have found solutions from within the virtual hosts declarations with an Alias

But as I am on a shared host, I cannot edit httpd.conf. 
So i have to do it from .htaccess

The important part here is to not redirect the user, only serve the main domains directory from an htaccess.

Comment: Use a rewrite without the [R] flag. That's all.

Comment: It isn't possible. .htaccess file paths are "locked" to be relative to the document root for the hostname (`domain.com` or `sub.domain.com`) being served. You can't break out of that sandbox using mod_rewrite or mod_alias. What you would need to do is point the subdomain at the same folder as the main domain, or have the hosting company do that for you.

Comment: That kind of depends on how you current host has implemented this subdomain-to-subfolder 'feature'. You could try using the proxy flag `[P]`